# In Excel, fiscal year from date not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

In Excel 2016, I am trying to display the fiscal year in a column next to one with the date of an appointment. The dates are formatted as "short date". The fiscal year runs 10/01/2019 through 09/30/2020. In cell U2, I have 10 set as the month the fiscal year starts in.

I am using this formula:
=YEAR(G2)+(MONTH(G2)>=$U$2)

For some dates, it correctly lists the fiscal year, but its listing dates like 05/06/2020 and 7/4/20 as FY21.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you adding the year and the month?

Comment: I was following what I read to do here: https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/date-and-time/get-fiscal-year-from-date Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: FWIW, I could not recreate this in a new worksheet. It may be some formatting or setup oddity and not an in-built issue. Can you recreate the issue in a new file?

Comment: You can always evaluate your formula (look for it in formula tab) to follow step by step how is calculated and understand what's wrong. Would be interesting to know how your formula could give wrong result.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!
This seems to be working:
=IF(MONTH(G5)>=10, YEAR(G5)+1, YEAR(G5))

Shout out to the video below for pointing me in the right direction, even though her formula didn't work for me:
https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-convert-dates-to-fiscal-quarters-and-years